# How to add a header to a WCF SOAP HTTPS/SSL Handshake?

Tags: wcf, ssl, https, user-agent, soap-client

I am working with a C# WCF Soap client that uses HTTPS/SSL and I'm in a bit of a pickle. I need every call from the client to contain a User-Agent header for reasons I won't explain. I'm able to add the header to my outgoing transactions like so:

```
using (var x = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{

    var header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("User-Agent", "user-agent",             
       "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    var result = base.Channel.myTransaction(names);
    return result;
}
```

However, this header is not applied to the initial SSL handshake call, as observed in fiddler. I'm intercepting all outgoing messages and the header is definitely on the "myTransaction" call but not on the handshake.

**So to put it simply, how do I add a header to the handshake that occurs before my transaction?** Is this even possible? I've found nothing online that shows how to override or even interact with the handshake call at all. It's also worth noting that my intercept binding only seems to catch my actual request, and not the handshake (while Fiddler catches the handshake but not the transaction - though I think that's expected).

Comment: SSL handshake happens before the client and the server can perform an HTTP transaction. It has been codified in several RFCs and your question does not make any sense (sorry). Maybe, explain the real need behind this idea of manipulating the handshake.

Comment: @EugèneAdell This is all correct. My problem here is that the handshake in WCF seems to happen automatically under the hood. I tell my client to send the Http Transaction and it makes the handshake before the main transaction. I need access to the handshake in order to add a header.